# php, регулярное выражение для поиска идентичных пар

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

прошу помощи. У меня есть текст, в котором расставлены мои собственные а-ля тег метки типа `[читайте_также]тексттексттекст[/читайте_также]`, `[прочее]тексттексттекст[/прочее]` и т.д. Причем допустима вложенность. Возможно ли написать регулярку, которая "выкусывает" такие вот пары, НО с учетом СВОЕГО замыкающего тега, а не ближайшего [/]. Сложность в том, что я не хочу ЯВНО указывать перечень `(читайте_также|прочее)`, а соорудить что то типа "заглянуть вперед, найти ближайший СВОЙ замыкающий "тег", и, расценивая УЖЕ ЭТОТ фрагмент как необходимый результат. - вырезать. Т.е. задача - заглянуть вперед и найти свою ближайшую замыкающую пару. Начал с `/\[[а-я_]+\].+?\[\/[а-я_]+\]/uis` но пока тупик что то UPD дада, я в курсе про обратные ссылки, но не могу осилить логику синтаксически

UPD Решение: `/\[([а-я_]+)\].+?\[\/\\1\]/uis`

Comment: обратные ссылки в помощь

Comment: это ясно, пока не могу понять как применить

Comment: в открывающем тэге обернуть `[а-я_]+` в группу, во закрывающем заменить  `[а-я_]+`  на ссылку `\1`

Comment: так так, спасибочки, я сейчас попробую...

Comment: Вау! Супер! Все получилось `/\[([а-я_]+)\].+?\[\/\\1\]/uis` Спасибо уважаемый!

Comment: Это не будет работать со вложенными тегами.

Answer (score 1):

Можно обернуть в группу название вашего тега и текст внутри него, и указать его в завершающем теге через `\1`

Пример:

```
$text = "[читайте_также]тексттексттекст[/читайте_также], [прочее]тексттексттекст[/прочее]";
preg_match_all('/\[([а-я_]+)\](.+?)\[\/\1\]/uis', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
  array(3) {
        [0]=>
    string(85) "[читайте_также]тексттексттекст[/читайте_также]"
        [1]=>
    string(25) "читайте_также"
        [2]=>
    string(30) "тексттексттекст"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
        [0]=>
    string(59) "[прочее]тексттексттекст[/прочее]"
        [1]=>
    string(12) "прочее"
        [2]=>
    string(30) "тексттексттекст"
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Примерно так, да, решение вынес в апдейт поста!

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov, лучше тогда не в вопросе указывать решение, а в ответе :) И если мой ответ помог, то проголосуйте за него ;)

Comment: в данном случае, вероятно имеет смысл использовать флаг `PREG_SET_ORDER`, и сам контент тэга в группу обернуть

Comment: @teran, согласен, спасибо за уточнение :)